# Laravel Elixir not combining scripts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I just did a clean install of laravel. Elixir is not combining my scripts. I am clueless about what's happening. I see the scripts task getting triggered but no files are output in public/js directory.

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass('style.scss')
        .scripts([
            'vendor/jquery.js',
            'vendor/foundation.min.js',
            'script.js'
        ], 'resources/assets/js', 'public/js/app.min.js')
        .scripts([
            'vendor/modernizr.js'
        ], 'resources/assets/js', 'public/js/modernizr.js');
});
```

It compiles sass properly.

This is the directory structure: https://www.uploady.com/#!/download/221Y0RI_aYe/V7eKiQHIw2gvyXVD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer. My second and third argument (input and output directory) to the scripts() function should be interchanged. Seems like this changed in the current version of elixir. Happy coding!

Edit (solution):

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass('style.scss')
        .scripts([
            'vendor/jquery.js',
            'vendor/foundation.min.js',
            'script.js'
        ], 'public/js/app.min.js', 'resources/assets/js')
        .scripts([
            'vendor/modernizr.js'
        ], 'public/js/modernizr.js', 'resources/assets/js');
});
```

Comment: Add example of working code, so people after you can refer to it please.

Comment: elixir.extend('scripts', function(scripts, outputDir, baseDir)

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question here: [laracast.com](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-elixir-multiple-sets-of-scripts)
The problem was that the version of laravel-elixir was not the latest version.
So have a look in your package.json and check which version you are running.
Maybe your problem is also the version you use for laravel-elixir.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```js
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less')
        .scripts([
            'vendor/underscore.min.js',
            'plugins/dropzone.js',
            'main.js',
            'autocomplete.js',
            'search.js',
            'reviews.js'
        ], 'resources/assets/js', 'public/js/app.js')
        .scripts([
            'admin.js',
            'admin-search.js'
        ], 'resources/assets/js/admin', 'public/js/app-admin.js');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel (5.4) is using **Laravel Mix** now! So basically you have a webpack file now. Take a look at the documentation:

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

Answer (score -1):

This is worked

```
elixir(function(mix) {
mix.sass('app.scss')

    mix.styles([
       'bootstrap.css',
        'sb-admin-2.css'

   ],'./public/css/all.css')


       mix.scripts([

           'bootstrap.min.js',
           'sb-admin-2.js'

       ], './public/js/app.js')



 });
```

Gulp Summary